# Changing a String key from a hashmap to an int

Tags: java, hashmap, int

I have a hashmap with a String as the key and an object as the value.

```
 private HashMap<String, object> asdf;
```

The String contains a year and school subjects like this

```
"2009: Math"
```

I need to retrieve that '2009' as an int. I tried some parseInt tricks but wasn't able to do so. Maybe I was doing it wrong.

Any tips, suggestions, guidance?

Comment: Show these "parseInt tricks"

Comment: What has the problem to do with a hash map? It is simply about parsing a string or did I miss something?

Comment: I tried something like 'Integer.parseInt(objectArray.keySet());' and 'NumberFormat.getInstance().parse(objectArray.keySet())' but they keySet() seems to be making incompatible.

Comment: Oh, because the keySet is just return a [set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) of key, not a String

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
            (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                 //We split up the string into array using ":" as filter, we remove the white space, and return the first array component
                 String key = entry.getKey().split(":")[0].trim(); 
                 int year = Integer.parseInt(key);
             }
```

Comment: Could you add a few words describing your solution?